# UART Interface of an 1993 Electric Typewriter

Tags: untagged

I recently acquired an electric typewriter. It is the "Triumph Adler Gabriele Cyclo". The unit does not have any outside electric interfaces, only the keyboard. After examining the pcb, I found a 4 pin header with RX TX GND 24V. When powering the unit on, it is sending 3 bytes with 4800baud.

My goal is to interface the electric typewriter with a micro controller.

But there is no documentation available. The only thing when searching online is this website: https://www.stcarchiv.de/stc1988/07/gabriele-9009-1

It helped me a lot, but my machine differs from the website.

By trial and error, I figured out that:

```
0xA0 - offline mode
0xA9 - online mode
```

**Is there any similar documentation available?**

Comment: `it is sending 3 bytes` ... what are they? ... what happens on if you type?

Comment: The company still exists, did you try asking them for some documentation?